# why the output is 2 not 7 ? how + sign makes it different

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
        int a=3;
        a +=2;
        a = +2;
        printf("%d",a);
}
```

The output of this program is 2 why ?

Comment: `a = +2;` is equivalent to `a = 2;`

Comment: The last thing you do before `printf` is assigning `2` to `a`. Not sure what else you expected.

Comment: `a += 2` is the same as `a = a + 2`. `a =+ 2` is equal to `a = +2` which is equal to `a = 2`

Comment: Have you tried running this in a debugger? Hint: what does "a = +2" actually do?. Hint: "= +" is not an operator.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ... + sign doesnt makes any sense here ?

Comment: @RakeshSaini Its how you're using it. `+=` means something. but `= +2` just means `=2`.

Comment: not yet bt now i'll @jdv

Comment: @RakeshSaini `operator+(int)` exists and does nothing to the value. It's not strictly wrong here, but it's not necessary either.

Comment: @RakeshSaini why do you think you can put `+` anywhere you want and it would not change expression? Do you think that `a = 2+;` should work? How about `+a=2;`?

Comment: do not panic bro @Slava... i found this program somewhere..executed and got confused...btw what i think is stackoverflow is meant for asking questions ri8

Comment: thanks everyone i got it .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to get a different output after assigning a variable to a value (immediately before printing it).

This is not magic.

`a = +2;` is same as `a= 2;`

You are overwriting the value of `a`.  so there is no use of `a+=2`.
You can directly write `int a=2`.

<sub>Interestingly, the compiler (any good one!) will probably eliminate the `a+=2` statement by using some technique known as dead code elimination.</sub>

`+2` is basically applying the unary oprator `+` to the integer `2`. And then it is assignment statement.

---

#### Unless you overloaded unary `+`it shouldn't make you feel out of context loooking at this behavior.

To be more precise, you can't overload `int` or builtin type. So there is no way , you are overloading that `+`. (And there is no user-defined type)(<sup>Peter Becker's comment</sup>)

Comment: You can't overload unary `operator+` for `int` (or any other builtin type). You can only overload operators when at least one user-defined type is involved.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Peter that's right.

Comment: @PeteBecker.: Please check it..I guess this is now complete? Thanks for suggetsions.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the output to be 7 your code should be

```
int main()
{
        int a=3;
        a +=2;
        a = a+2;
        printf("%d",a);
}
```

By typing a = +2; before your printf line you just assign the positive value of 2 to your a variable.

a += 2 is the same thing as a = a + 2

a =+2 sets the value to 2 no matter what the value was before.